# how to include variable inside ExtensionContent in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this part of code for XML generation and want to be able to fetch and call variable from inside `ExtensionContent` for example change this value `OTcwNjljYzUwY2JlZTI4NWRkNDM2NmVhMDM3MGJhM2NjNDZlZTJjMjYxZDkwYzUyM2RiZjYyODNkNmQ4ZTM3OA==` with variable added in the code

```
ExtensionContent = @"<sig:UBLDocumentSignatures xmlns:sig=""urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2"" xmlns:sac=""urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2"" xmlns:sbc=""urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2"">
                                            <sac:SignatureInformation>                                     
                                                <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                                                <ds:Signature xmlns:ds=""http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"" Id=""signature"">
                                                    <ds:SignedInfo>
                                                        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11""/>
                                                        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256""/>
                                                        <ds:Reference Id=""invoiceSignedData"" URI="""">
                                                            <ds:Transforms>
                                                                <ds:Transform Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"">
                                                                    <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)</ds:XPath>
                                                                </ds:Transform>
                                                                <ds:Transform Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"">
                                                                    <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)</ds:XPath>
                                                                </ds:Transform>
                                                                <ds:Transform Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"">
                                                                    <ds:XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:AdditionalDocumentReference[cbc:ID='QR'])</ds:XPath>
                                                                </ds:Transform>
                                                                <ds:Transform Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11""/>
                                                            </ds:Transforms>
                                                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256""/>
                                                            <ds:DigestValue>lYQcYGXl6hCf+ZZPNdr1wajasZBRGKXlNepHUG+S4HA=</ds:DigestValue>
                                                        </ds:Reference>
                                                        <ds:Reference Type=""http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties"" URI=""#xadesSignedProperties"">
                                                            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256""/>
                                                            <ds:DigestValue>OTcwNjljYzUwY2JlZTI4NWRkNDM2NmVhMDM3MGJhM2NjNDZlZTJjMjYxZDkwYzUyM2RiZjYyODNkNmQ4ZTM3OA==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                        </ds:Reference>
                                                    </ds:SignedInfo>
                                                    <ds:SignatureValue></ds:SignatureValue>
                                                    <ds:KeyInfo>
                                                        <ds:X509Data>
                                                            <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                                                        </ds:X509Data>
                                                    </ds:KeyInfo>
                                                    <ds:Object>
                                                        <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades=""http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"" Target=""signature"">
                                                            <xades:SignedProperties Id=""xadesSignedProperties"">
                                                                <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                                                    <xades:SigningTime>2022-03-31T12:13:18Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                                                    <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                                                        <xades:Cert>
                                                                            <xades:CertDigest>
                                                                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm=""http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256""/>
                                                                                <ds:DigestValue>ZGNjZTk3MGIzYjg0M2FlODczNGIyMDQ3ZjczOTM2NjgyNjljYmQ4NGYyZThkOTlmY2ZjYTU0ODFhZWE3MjE4NA==</ds:DigestValue>
                                                                            </xades:CertDigest>
                                                                            <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=eInvoicing</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>1641728828389</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                                            </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                                        </xades:Cert>
                                                                    </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                                                </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                                            </xades:SignedProperties>
                                                        </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                                                    </ds:Object>
                                                </ds:Signature>
                                            </sac:SignatureInformation>
                                        </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>".ToXmlElement()
                    }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called `xsd.exe` in the .NET Framework Tools.

It allows you to create 1 or more C# classes that matches your XML.  Then you can use the XML Serializer to deserialize your XML to .NET objects, update your property, then serialize the objects back to XML and save.

This is an article from Microsoft that contains more information about xsd.exe

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen